# Am I wrong to expect more initiative from the tech lead?

Tags: communication, teamleader

I am new to the company and I feel like the lead behaves like a normal developer. Here's how our last conversation went:

Me: "Hey I'm using this feature but it doesn't work. Is there any configuration I need to do?"

Lead: "No, it should work."

Me: "It's not working: I did these steps and here's a screenshot."

Lead: "Oh man then I have no idea."

And that's all. This is how all our conversations usually go. I'm here kinda confused saying to myself, "Wait wut? That's all you gonna say? you're not inquiring as to why something deployed is not working? Perhaps suggest me a call and I'll show you my screen?"

He has ignored 2 or 3 questions in chat but overall he replies to all my questions. I feel like he tries to brush me off. I understand that he might be busy but hey, you're a lead.

He is a good developer and it seems he pulls off difficult tasks but I am also concerned about his age because he is young and I feel that his soft skills are unpolished (he also seems oblivious of what gameplay politics are because he gave me tools to responsibilize him for wasted hours but I don't want to resort to this).

So far I have done my tasks because I am experienced but I feel like many hours are wasted in trying to figure out things he could answer in 10 minutes but he only limits himself to answer simple questions.

Some key aspects:

- I have senior experience and I have been lead myself but my current position is normal developer.
- All my questions are business related stuff I could never figure out myself.
- Although he acknowledges his position as lead he has stated that he is not my boss (the scrum master also says this to me, the hierarchy here is confusing to me).

Am I wrong to expect more from him or should I just do my job at whatever pace I can?

Edit: I'm guessing the people who voted to close the question are not developers because there is a standard a basis for the duties of a lead as explained by the first answer so please refrain from voting to close a question you're ignorant about! thanks

Comment: You wrote "he might be busy" and you are new at the company. Those may be two of the main reasons. Just be patient, give him a little time, and try to build a "friendly bridge". After he sees that you can accomplish difficult tasks on your own, he will realize that you are a "capable developer and good team player". Then, he will be more willing to give long answers to technical issues.

Comment: I'm not a developer so I don't know what responsibilities that being a tech lead usually carries with it. Is it his responsibility to lead projects, progress, deliverables? Is it his job to mentor and assist you?

Comment: We can't judge whether a particular person in your company is doing the job expected of him nor can we answer who you should be asking those types of questions to. The person you need to talk to is your actual manager to figure out what you should be doing in this situation because the status quo isn't working out. Advice on how to have those conversations is a more appropriate question for this site.

Answer (score 7):

**Lead means different things at different companies**

At some companies, the lead is meant to be the great unblocker, a systems expert who knows a ton and spends their time working with their developers to knock out the hard problems.

At others, it is the title for the guy everyone calls for technical support. Everyone always wants the most important person they can get ahold of as they think their problem is important, so they just go right to the top. If "everyone" includes management, that problem solver becomes the lead.

At others, it is someone who can tolerate meetings and frequently has little to do with development at all. They can not speak to development team members for days. They are there to sit in on meetings and relay orders and capacity information back and forth. They are essentially a coordinator.

At others, it is just the best developer and they behave no differently except that they can code all day in an office rather than a cubicle/hot desk. I had an old team lead where nobody was sure what he did all day as we didn't speak to him much. His team of developers did not know what he was doing as he was mostly in his office. Then he left. It turned out that he was single-handedly handling all support and maintenance tasks on numerous systems, many of which we had never heard of.

> I feel like many hours are wasted in trying to figure out things he could answer in 10 minutes but he only limits himself to answer simple questions

This expectation is only compatible with the first type of lead developer and many companies are not happy having this type of developer as in their mind they are just someone who is not writing code.

> he also seems oblivious of what gameplay politics are because he gave me tools to responsibilize him for wasted hours

He is young and yet in a position of power. I wouldn't be so eager to judge him as politically inept. Incredible amounts of absurd can make sense in a corporate environment.

> all my questions are business related stuff I could never figure out myself

There is a good chance that he also doesn't know. It is very easy to learn very little about what the business actually does as a software developer, especially if a lot of it is a parade of bug fixes and small feature builds.

More support would be ideal, but that is not compatible with how many companies operate.

Comment: "*His team of developers did not know what he was doing as he was mostly in his office.*..." These anecdotes are fascinating.

Comment: @DKNguyen so many people wondered what it was he did all day and assumed he was disengaged and just hovering until he found something new. We were very right on the disengaged part. We were very wrong on the "hovering" part. He was handling a pile of stuff that nobody properly appreciated.

Comment: @DKNguyen it really was proof of the importance of showing off your work through as here was this guy holding up the infrastructure and figuring out ways to pay next to nothing for things (as governments don't spend on non-salary stuff without a pile of paperwork), single handedly handling the after-hours support work, and ensuring that fragile systems didn't collapse and people were not sure that he did much of anything.